# T-SQL command to log in as a different user?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, logins

Is there a T-sql command, like the Oracle "Connect" which lets me change the user that I am logged in as?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the EXECUTE AS command:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx

Comment: Future users: Be really careful using `EXECUTE AS` on a connection from a connection pool (ie: any SqlConnection in .NET): it automatically resets the connection to prevent security leaks, which will break all the rest of the active connections from that pool. Furthermore, this will only happen sporadically when you're in a threaded environment, so you might not figure it out for months. Not that I know anyone who that happened to...

Comment: If you want to bust the pooling you can add "Pooling=false" to your connection string in .NET (`Pooling` in the SqlConnectionStringBuilder).  I recognize that these tips aren't 100% DBA specific, but they might bite users reading this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try SetUser 'username' too. To revert just run SetUser. Verify by running select suser_name()

Comment: [`"SETUSER is included for backward compatibility only. SETUSER may not be supported in a future release of SQL Server. We recommend that you use EXECUTE AS instead."`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186297.aspx)

Comment: select suser_name() appears to show the login in use for me rather than the user name.  Think the the call for getting user name is select DB_Name().  +1 because I didnt know how to do this either though!

Answer (score 0):

Using sqlcmd.exe or Management Studio in SQLCMD mode, you can use the `:connect` macro to change the connection in the middle of a script. (See [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/the-sqlcmd-workbench/) for the full syntax -- weirdly, I can't find documentation for this on MSDN.)

If you just need to test something as a different principal, you can use [`EXECUTE AS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362.aspx) to impersonate the principal, and [`REVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178632.aspx) to back out.

Answer (score -1):

The question has multiple answers, dependent on the context of 'changing the user that I am logged in as.'

A public website will have one or a few 'user accounts' which are used by every site visitor. Even through those accounts, it may be necessary to elevate a permission to execute, for instance, dynamic SQL in solving a multivariable search requirement.

Errand Sommarskog has a very detailed discussion on the security and management of user accounts via T-SQL in stored procedures.
http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html